# How Do I Typeset Horner's Method / Scheme of Regular Synthetic Division and Expanded Synthetic Division for Monic Divisors and Non-Monic Divisors?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode, pgfmath, polynom, polynomials

I personally do not like the `\polyhornerscheme[x=x_0]{<a_0 + a_1 x + ... a_n x^n>}` macro of the [`polynom`](https://ctan.org/pkg/polynom) package because of personal aesthetic preferences and how it doesn't have a general enough use case for synthetic division since it is primarily focused on the polynomial evaluation aspect.

***How do I programmatically typeset Horner's method / scheme of regular synthetic division and expanded synthetic division for monic divisors and non-monic divisors by defining a macro*** `\polysynthdiv{<dividend>}{<divisor>}` ***with three different possible cases for each? (possibly using TikZ***

Preferably, ***I want the spacing to be proper and not too tight and I also want a bar separating the remainder from the quotient and I want an optional argument*** `[show]` ***to toggle the variables (e.g., x) to be seen on top of the dividend's coefficients.***

#### • Case 1 (Regular Synthetic Division)

I want to simply type `\polysynthdiv{x^3 - 2x^2 - 4}{x - 3}` for

[image: \polysynthdiv{x^3 - 2x^2 - 4}{x - 3}]

and `\polysynthdiv[show]{x^3 - 2x^2 - 4}{x - 3}` for

[image: \polysynthdiv[show]{x^3 - 2x^2 - 4}{x - 3}]

#### • Case 2 (Expanded Synthetic Division for Monic Divisor)

I want to simply type `\polysynthdiv{x^3 - 12x^2 - 42}{x^2 + x - 3}` for

[image: \polysynthdiv{x^3 - 12x^2 - 42}{x^2 + x - 3}]

and `\polysynthdiv[show]{x^3 - 12x^2 - 42}{x^2 + x - 3}` for

[image: \polysynthdiv[show]{x^3 - 12x^2 - 42}{x^2 + x - 3}]

#### • Case 3 (Expanded Synthetic Division for Non-Monic Divisor)

I want to simply type `\polysynthdiv{6x^3 + 5x^2 - 7}{3x^2 - 2x - 1}` for

[image: \polysynthdiv{6x^3 + 5x^2 - 7}{3x^2 + 2x - 1}]

and `\polysynthdiv[show]{6x^3 + 5x^2 - 7}{3x^2 - 2x - 1}` for

[image: \polysynthdiv[show]{6x^3 + 5x^2 - 7}{3x^2 + 2x - 1}]

Thank you.

Comment: @MS-SPO I would personally accept a reasonable answer that uses 6 different commands each as long as they fit the syntax using only 2 mandatory arguments {<dividend>}{<divisor>}

Comment: From a programming perspective I’d typeset each of your 6 use cases and many more manually, i.e. without any option. Variability is king here. // Next I’d have a look at commonalities and differences and see how to treat the whole in elegant ways. // Finally these findings need to be put into macros, like the ones the mentioned package uses. It will be a long route. // As an alternative try to extract a handful of useful templates from your use cases, which might be easier and quicker to obtain and maintain.